# Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, validation, if-statement

I'm checking the objects validity in Matlab with the combination of zeros in the array. I want to use && operator to do so but when I use that in a single if statement, it givs me the error:
**Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.**

**My Code:**

```
for ii=1:1000
 if (Vec(ii,:) ~= 0) && (isvalid(MyObj))
%opeartions
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those operators perform shortcut evaluation similar to the comparable C operators.   That is a || b  only evaluates b of a is false, and a && b only evaluates b if a true.   It will not do this shortcut evaluation on a point by point basis.

Since at least one of your operands appears to be a vector of boolean conditions (`Vec(ii,:)~=0`),   Matlab is telling you that the shortcut evaluation cannot be peformed.

You put this in an if,  so you needed a single scalar boolean anyway.  I would guess that you meant the scalar first operand as `any(Vec(ii,:)~=0)` rather than the vector.